# Need Assistance Removing Persistent Malware from WordPress and cPanel

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, shared-hosting, namecheap

I recently discovered malware in my WordPress installation and cPanel on my shared hosting server (namecheap). I took immediate action by creating a backup, resetting my cPanel, and installing the backup locally via WAMP. I also replaced all 'wp-admin' and 'wp-includes' files with the official WordPress files, and removed any suspicious files I could find. After these measures, I scanned the website using Wordfence, and it appeared to be clean.

However, when I attempted to install the backup in my cPanel, the hosting server became overloaded. Upon further investigation, I found that the malware had once again created files in the 'lscache' directory.

I'm seeking assistance from someone who may have experience in resolving this persistent malware issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have a domain with Namecheap and their support staff are generally very helpful in resolving these issues. Have you created a support ticket yet? Also this question is more for ServerFault, not StackOverflow.